# Reading textfile into 2d array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, bufferedreader, readfile

I am trying to read a given text file filled with a bunch of doubles, the text file looks something like this(no spaces between each line):

> 0, 0.007133248, 0.003747135, 0.0034464097, 0.009517824, 0.0036065334,
>   0.007921185, 0.0041013476
>
> 1, 0.006223865, 5.804103E-4, 5.6967576E-4, 0.008850083, 0.003269921,
>   3.7322243E-4, 0.0011008179
>
> 2, 0.0051101227, 0.008973722, 0.0013274436, 0.00922496, 0.0050817304,
>   0.004631279, 0.0069321943

essentially **1000** rows with **8** columns, and am trying to turn this into a 2d array of data[1000][8], am having trouble iterating through the data though. Heres what I have so far, any help would be appreciated!

```
  public static void readFile2() throws IOException{

    Double[][] data = new Double[1000][8];
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Roman/Documents/workspace/cisc124/Logger (1).csv")));

    while (scanner.hasNext() && scanner !=null) {
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(row<data.length && col<8){
        data[row][col] = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next());
        col++;
        //System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(data));

    }
    col=0;
    row++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: What code exactly do you have problems with? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more convenient reading thefile line by line..

```
String[] data = new String[1000];
int row = 0;
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "utf-8"));         

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        data[row]= line;
        row++;
    }
    br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and at the end do the same

```
System.out.println(Arrays.ToString(data));
```

or if you need the element at a given index then split a row and use `Double.parse();`